# What prevents me from using $.ajax to load another domain's html?

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, screen-scraping, web-scraping

My domain:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>  
<html>
<head>
<title>scrape</title>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <script>
        $.ajax({url:'http://their-domain.com/index.html',
        dataType:'html',
            success:function(data){console.log(data);}
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

What prevents me from being able to scrape their-domain? Any work around?

Addendum: thank you all for the suggestions to use a server side script, but I am for the moment interested in solving this problem exclusively using the client.

If I format the request using "jsonp" I do at least get a response, but with the following error:"Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <". So I am getting a response from their-domain but the parser expects it to be json. (As well it should.) I am hacking through this trying to see if their is a way to trick the client into accepting this response. Please understand that I know this is atypical.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>  
<html>
<head>
<title>scrape</title>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <script>
        $.ajax({url:'http://their-domain.com/index.html',
        dataType:'jsonp',
            success:function(data){console.log(data);}
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy or https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript

Comment: if you get this to work, which you won't, they will need to update/patch the hole. There's a reason it doesn't work and as almost ever answer has pointed out....SOP.

Answer (score 6):

There are Four ways to get around [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy)

1. Proxy - You request it from your server, your server requests it from other domain, your server returns it to the browser
2. [Flash cross domain policy](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/articles/crossdomain_policy_file_spec.html) - other domain must add a crossdomain.xml file to their site
3. [Cross domain HTTP header](http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/#access-control-allow-origin-response-hea) - other domain must add an `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header to their page
4. [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP) - It's a json web service that provides a callback function.  Other domain must implement this.

Note: The **ONLY** way to do it without the other domain's help is #1, routing it through your own server.

Answer (score 2):

It's the **Same Origin Policy**, which prevents cross-domain requests.  If you want to scrape html, you are better off writing a server side process to get the content, then use ajax to make a request against your server, which contains the harvested data.

Answer (score 2):

the [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) prevents client side scripts from getting data from domains that are not from the originator for the request. You would need a server side script to act as a proxy

Answer (score 0):

One workaround is to make a server-side script (eg. PHP) to get the page, and have `$.ajax` call that.