# JQuery AJAX JSONP Invalid Label

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, jsonp

I know this question has been asked, but I cannot get it working.

I execute the following AJAX request:

```
function dislikeMeme(memeId) {
    $.ajax({
        dataType: "jsonp",
        url: "http://<url>.com/dislike/" + memeId,
        data: { 
            u: "username",
            p: "password"
        },
        jsonpCallback: 'successCallback'
    });
}

function successCallback(data) {
    alert("Test"); // Not firing because of previous 'Invalid label' error
};
```

Looking at firebug I see that the request was successful, but there is an `Invalid Label` error which fires the Error callback of the request. The response of the request is as follows:

```
{
    "id":6220673,
    "myScore":-1,
    "msg":"Not loved"
}
```

I see that the parentheses are causing JavaScript to interpret the response as an object, but I know this is the format I am retrieving, isn't there anyway to parse this before it causes an error?

I also see that the URL of the page returning this information is:

```
http://<url>.com/dislike/123456?callback=successCallback&u=username&p=password&_123456789
```

Everything is working perfectly except this `Invalid label` error. Does anyone have any ideas?

Thanks in advance everyone

Comment: Your JSON is not JSONP. If it is not JSONP, there is no way to process it if it is cross-domain and not CORS.

Comment: @KevinB I am using JSONP to get this working cross-domain. The server is sending the correct callback but also returning JSON. I just want to stop the invalid label error.

Comment: To stop the invalid label error, make the server return only JSONP if a callback parameter is passed in. It should look like `successCallback({"foo":"bar"})` given your `?callback=successCallback`

Comment: @KevinB If I have no control over the server, is there no way to stop this? The request is successful it's just generating this error. If possible I'd like to ignore it and continue the success callback.

Comment: You can't. If the server isn't properly returning JSONP when you request for it to be JSONP, there's nothing you can do clientside that will make it work.  You'll have to request it using your server instead (or some other server, such as the YQL proxy).

Comment: @KevinB I see that you mentioned CORS, how can I get my request enabled with this?

Comment: For one, the server would have to support it. I would start by looking there. Two, CORS is not supported in all browsers. If you wish to support IE7, CORS is out of the question, and for IE8+ (maybe even 10? i dont know yet) you'll have to handle the ajax request yourself because jQuery's $.ajax won't work with CORS requests in IE.

Comment: I threw CORS in there because if i didn't someone's going to come back and say *"Yes you can, use CORS!"* I don't really consider it an option due to the number of people on business computers still running IE7.

Comment: @KevinB Thanks for your answers, I see that it's not currently possible. I'm curling the page instead on my server-side and this will suffice. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A server that can handle JSONP takes the callback paramater (can be different parameter depending on WS) and passes it in the response.  So the response from the server should be:

```
successCallback({
"id":6220673,
"myScore":-1,
"msg":"Not loved"
})
```

If you don't have control over the server your only route is proxy.  See my cross domain answer for information on getting around same origin policy.
[What prevents me from using $.ajax to load another domain's html?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8944656/what-prevents-me-from-using-ajax-to-load-another-domains-html/8944743#8944743)