# Style button based on api call

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am creating a page that will display the status of several servers in a cluster. I have created a status route on my web service that simple returns 'ok' if the server is up-and-running properly and some error if it is not. I want to have several buttons (maybe better option?) that display green if the api call returns ok and red if not. One wrinkle is that these calls will be cross-domain albeit inside our corporate firewall.

Simple enough but I am a webservice developer that has next-to-no experience in this area. My thought was to make a call to each servers status route on page load and set the style. I am embarrassed to say that I am honestly not sure where to start. every tutorial I find seems to be missing some piece of the puzzle for it to 'click' for me.

So, my ultimate questions is whether there is a known tutorial that meets the following criteria:

- html5/CSS3 enabled (preferably responsive design for mobile display)
- jquery/angularjs libraries if necessary
- cross-domain api calls supported
- button (drawing) based on api call results.

If this is easy enough to just show with straight html and js in a question response body that would be fine as well. the only reason I added the other pieces is that this is just one small piece of a dashboard I'm building that will be integrating statistical graphs and management capabilities. So, starting with these capabilities would be ideal compared to integrating later.

Thanks in advance. and please let me know if this question is not specific enough. I will edit.

Comment: I'm not sure I can give you a tutorial that meets exactly what you want.  But I can give you an answer about cross domain api calls: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8944656/what-prevents-me-from-using-ajax-to-load-another-domains-html/8944743#8944743  JSONP would be the solution that best fits your scenario as you control the webservices.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You dont necessarily need a jQuery based solution its easy but having a pure CSS / JS solution is also an option. If you are just using jQuery for changing a color or adding a class you are most likely doing it wrong.

The most common method of attaining what you want to attain is doing a remote call to the server, you can use XHR for this, depending on the response and state of the XHR you can always update your view. I am providing an example of a progress bar , to attain what you want you can follow a similar approach.

For example you are creating a progress bar.
with HTML as :

```
  <div class="progress_bar">
      <div class="progress"></div>
  </div>
```

The CSS part contains.

```
   .progress_bar{
      display:inline-block;
      position:relative;
      margin:20px;
      width:100%; 
      height:40px;
      max-width:100px; /* For Computers */
   }
   .progress_bar .progress{
      height:100%;
      position:absolute;
      left:0px;
      top:0px;
      width:0%;
   }
   @media(max-width:320px){
      max-width:100%;
      margin:10px;
   }
   .progress_bar::before{
        display:block; text-align:center;
        content:"Loading";
        color:black;
        font-size:16px;
    }
    .progress_bar.completed::before{
        content:"Finished";
    }
    .progress_bar.error::before{
        content:"Error Occured";
    }
```

Now you can have a JS API call ( Say you are downloading a file )

you can just change the width of the .progress element.

```
function ProgressBar(elem){
   var bar = elem.getElementsByClassName('progress')[0];
   this.setProgress = function(x){
       bar.style.width = x + '%';
   }
   this.completed = function(){
       elem.classList.add("completed");
   }
   this.errored = function(){
       elem.classList.add("errored");
   }
}
```

Now you can just make an object and use the new XHR2.0 API's for controlling your JS part, but doing so via adding classes etc, you can attain responsive design as some changes or some logic in js causes a CSS class to be applied, this class can have multiple rules defined for it using Media queries. Hope this helps.

For more on XHR2.0 you can read here http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/xhr2/

Comment: This won't fit his need.  XmlHttpRequest DOES work for web service calls but his is cross-domain.  If the browser or server doesn't support CORS it won't work.  jQuery isn't only used for css style, it is also used for the AJAX call which takes care of CORS. JSONP, & XHR.

Comment: if CORS messes, so will jQuery

Comment: JQuery is certainly not required for this but it is a nice library for some other pieces of the site and has code that is best not to replicate.Several great answers but I think this may be the most appealing. Thank you!

Comment: @Darkyen Yes, but you can easily switch to JSONP versus building your own library for this

Comment: I'd rather stick to my own jsonp heck its barely a few lines of code :-|, and most of the cases i use jQuery is when its really really really required which is really really really rare , mostly when i required x-browser compatability

Comment: @Darkyen A simple implementation is only a few lines of code, but odds are that your implementation could have many improvements vs a library that is open source with may people working on it and using their experience to build it up.

Comment: @Justin I really really really doubt that... jQuery is bloatware it started a library and ended up as a frameworkbaray

Answer (score 1):

This link is enough to understand responsive Design:
http://mobile.smashingmagazine.com/2013/05/29/the-state-of-responsive-web-design/

jquery/angularjs libraries would help you speed up your development, so, take one.

cross-domain api calls supported <-- generally not a problem

button (drawing) based on api call results.<-- change css class while your result changed

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that you can find tutorial with all your requirements, the easiest way for you, if you only need to display buttons is to use jQuery Mobile, so it'll show good looking buttons for browsers and mobile devices. You don't need to use JavaScript frameworks like BackboneJS/AngularJS for this.

And for cross domain request you can use [http://easyxdm.net](http://easyxdm.net/wp/) there are a good examples, so you'll not get lost.

Answer (score 0):

This can easily be accomplished in jQuery.

There are many ways to go about it, but an example of changing a "button" color can be: `$("#server1").css("background-color", "#0000AA");` This will select the element in your html with an `id` of server1 and add/change the css value of `background-color` to `#0000AA`.  For more flexibility you can use css classes, there is a little more logic to it because normally you will be toggling it between `.addClass` & `removeClass`.

Now that you know the simplest way to change a css property on an html element, you are looking at doing the web service call.  There are 2 approaches, 1 - Your client and server support CORS, 2 - You use JSONP.  JSONP is an easier route and to use it all you need to do is modify your web service to look for a parameter of `callback` in the request from the client.  After that all you need to do is wrap the response from the server in whatever value is given.

EG: Say you have `callback=complete` in the request, basically you wrap it like so: `complete( { status: ok });`.  JSONP works by interpreting the results from the webservice as a script which will execute the callback function with the results of the server, thus making them available for you to work with in your callback function.  After you modify the service to do that, you can use jQuery's Ajax method to make a call to the webservice and get the data.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "http://internalserver/myservice.svc/GetServerStatus",
    datatype: "jsonp",
    contentType: "application/json",
    success: function(data) { alert(data.status); }
});
```

When the call finishes, the function defined for `success` will fire give you access to the results.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mw7G9/3/) to show example of it in action.

Comment: Why would jQuery be needed for anything ?

Comment: @Darkyen It wouldn't, but it simiplifies the amount of code written and knowledge js you need to know to accomplish the same task.  The OP also listed jQuery's use as being acceptable.

Comment: what you said is why we [at the js room] hate jQuery, if you dont know js you must not use jQuery! seriously writing blind code and driving blind are same things ! you might still be alive but u never know whats going on! and what can happen

Comment: @Darkyen jQuery's purpose was to enable faster development and less code.  jQuery handles may of the issues that would require explicit resolution by the developer in the past.  jQuery IS javascript.  You will be driving blind either way if you don't learn.  If you work for clients and you are re-writing code just because you don't want to learn or don't like that someone made a better product than you, you are just stealing from your client.